# How to setup SSL on an IIS development server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

Our team has a Windows 2008 server which is used primary for a common IIS dev box.

I want to enable SSL on one of the websites on IIS, so that it can only be accessed via HTTPS.

I created a self-signing certificate in IIS and installed it. However when I access the website via the browser (Chrome, Firefox or IE - doesn't matter), it always gives the scary..."this is not secure" screen. I've tried installing the certificate on my own computer, rebooting and I still get that screen.

One thing that I noticed is when I create a self-signed certificate, it adds the domain name to it...for instance, the name of the box is webIIS and our login domain is COMPANYDOMAIN. So it will say that the certificate was created by webIIS.COMPANYDOMAIN.com. This url resolves to nothing, since there is no such thing.

Am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Do you intend for this website to be used externally?

Comment: @AaronMason No, never.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't intend to use this website externally, and you have a domain, you therefore have an internal certificate authority (CA).  You should be able to create a signing request to send to your internal CA that will give you what you need for SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Self-Signed SSL's are untrusted, if you want a Trusted SSL, you will need to purchase one from a Certificate Authority.

Read More about [how-does-ssl-really-work](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your COMPANYDOMAIN.COM Certificate Authority to create a certificate.

All the computers inside your COMPANYDOMAIN.COM will trust the certificate.

["Active Directory Certificate Services Step-by-Step Guide"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772393(v=ws.10).aspx)